# Is there a callback to the app delegate when a remote notification is received?

Tags: ios, push-notification

After receiving the remote notification and the user takes action (other than close/dismiss), the app delegate gets callbacks:

> -(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
>   fetchCompletionHandler:(void
>   (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

or if the app is registered for notification actions:

> -(void) application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
>   forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void
>   (^)())completionHandler

My question is does the app get a callback when the remote notification is received?  That is before the user takes any action.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: @SausageMachine clarified my question...

Comment: Why do you need to know that the notification has reached the device before being sent to the app?

Comment: @rmaddy we're in the middle of designing a system and the backend guy asked me if it's possible to get a delegate call back when notification is received...  i just want to double check the SO community.  thanks for your response

Comment: @SausageMachine I beg the difference.  I love to talk to fellow developers.  Thanks for chiming in.

Comment: @Loozie. Its possible to send an app-directed push (called silent or background push) to the app. The app can receive that and then post a local notification if the user needs to see something. Hence in effect this is the same as what you were asking (as the user gets to see the notification and the app knows the notification is there because it put it here). However, if the app has been forcefully terminated by the user, the background push will not get delivered to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the app doesn't get any indication that the notification has reached the device. It only gets a delegate call when the notification actually gets sent to the app as you describe in the two cases in your question.

Answer (score 2):

```
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound,.badge])
        print("NOtification received")
    }

    public func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    print("original body was : \(response.notification.request.content.title)")
    print("Tapped in notification")

    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for thanks.

I have this callback for notification received: 
`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {}` 

And this callback for notification opened: 
`func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {}`

Comment: The 'willPresent' seems to be called only if the app is in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible to make use of background update notifications, as described in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app
However the use-cases for this solution are limited by the low number of notifications that are allowed to be sent in this way (the docs currently state "don't try to send more than 2 or 3 per hour").

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Of course app gets callback of these below delegates method when remote notification is received.

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    print("DEVICE TOKEN = \(deviceToken)")
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print(error)
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    print(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: didReceiveRemoteNotification method is invoked when app is in foreground but not in the case when app is not running or terminated by the user.

Comment: Yes, Of Course it's like that you can't get any callback when your app is terminated but you can get callback when you tap on that notification to open the app or whatever action you are doing on tapping. And below is the delegate method to check response of notification. Check my another answer. @Sumeet.Jain